# Django & Python : Format a FloatField in django form by adding separators

Tags: python, django, django-forms

Well I dont know how to do this on django, so please help me do so.

my float field is like :

```
montant= forms.FloatField(initial="0",required = False)
```

I want to show separators in my numbers to be lisible

**Example:**

- when I write on the field the number is like : 1000000.00

**what I need**

- when writing on the field is I want the number looks like : 1 000 000.00

Any help please ? Thank You in advance

Comment: Do you want theses numbers to be thousand-separated in the `input` fields or after you display them in {{tags}}?

Comment: I want these numbers to be thousand-separated in the input

Comment: I believe this has to be done with Javascript and doesn't really have anything to do with Django itself. E.g. see [this tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/auto-formatting-input-value--cms-26745).

Comment: I guess you're right . I'll see the tutorial and give a feedback. Thank you so much

Comment: The tutorial you proposed to me is very helpful. You can turn your comment to an answer so I can accept it as an answer to my question. Thank you So much

Comment: Glad it helped! I've added my comment as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As stated in my comment, your particular case (thousand-separated numbers in the `input` fields) is better solved with using Javascript for styling, rather than Django itself.

I've suggested following [this tutorial](https://webdesign.tutsplus.com/tutorials/auto-formatting-input-value--cms-26745)'s section 1 "How to Format a Currency Value", which describes how to capture, sanitize and change the displayed numbers in the `input` with JS (and jquery).

Answer (score 2):

You can use a template filter for this.
In your template you render your field like this `{{montant|readable_integer}}`
By applying the readable_string filter that you can define yourself.

The filter

```
from django import template
register = template.Library()

@register.filter()
def readable_integer(integer):
    readable=str(integer).split(".")[0][::-1]
    readable=[readable[i:i+3] for i in range(0, len(readable), 3)]
    if len(str(integer).split("."))==1:
        end=""
    else:
        end="."+str(integer).split(".")[1]
    return " ".join(readable[::-1])+end
```

Comment: thank you for your answer, but I need thse numbers to be thousand-separated in the input . not in the template